# What is the minimum required length of a magnetic to deflect particle of a given momentum?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, classical-electrodynamics

I know that the radius of curvature follows the equation:
$$r = \frac{p_T}{q B}$$
where $p_T$ is the transverse momentum (with respect to the magnetic field), $q$ the particle's charge and $B$ the magnetic field intensity. I would like to know what is the minimum length $L$ of the magnetic field to be sure that the particle is deflected, since the motion is not a 2D circumference, but a 3D spiral. Is it enough to have $L = r$, or should a greater length be adopted?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by the "length of magnetic field"? the size of the region on which the magnetic field acts, or what? and if yes, do you mean its size in the direction along the magnetic field, or transversally, or both? Also, even if the region is very short, the particle will still have time to be _a little bit_ deflected (like a few degrees) so I guess the answer will have to depend on how much deflection (in degrees) is good enough for you...

Comment: I mean the size of the region on which the magnetic field acts (transversally, in particular along the incoming beam direction, that is $z$). I would like to deflect them so they will not be detected in the immediately downstream detector. Obviously the angle then depends on its angular acceptance, but let's suppose it covers very large angles (until 80-90 degrees). Sorry if my question was not accurate.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Then, I think you should be ok as soon as the region is just a tiny bit longer than $r$ (if it's exactly $r$ and the detector is very large, I guess you could still have particles hitting it tangentially). If I can find the time I will add a response with a picture to show why...

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee that a particle will not be able to cross the region on which the magnetic field acts, the length of this region (along the direction of $\vec{p}_T$) should be at least $r$. You are right that if the particle has some initial impulsion along $\vec{B}$ the trajectory of the particle will be a spiral, but the dynamics *in the direction* of $\vec{B}$ is completely disconnected from the dynamics *orthogonal* to $\vec{B}$: in other words, for a given $\vec{p}_T$ the *projection* of the trajectory on the plane orthogonal to $\vec{B}$ will be the same.

[image: trajectories for different initial impulsion]